# How can i deploy changed files from teamcity into Artifactory?

Tags: teamcity, artifactory

I'm explicitly mentioning the file names under the custom artifacts path section to deploy the changed/ modified files to the artifactory. Is there any way Teamcity detects only the changed files and moves to the artifactory?

Is it possible to run a custom script for that?

Comment: if you have maven or gradle based project the easiest way to create a target like publish and just call it from maven or gradle build step.

Comment: btw [TeamCity Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/TeamCity+Artifactory+Plug-in)

Comment: I have 10 files. 7 are unchanged and the 3 are modified. I want only those modified files to be deployed. I'm trying for sql files.

Comment: you can use any script build step and call Artifactory REST API to publish artifacts.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using TeamCity Artifactory plugin, then, the plugin is using checksum deploy, that means that, if I'll use your example, if you have 10 files that 7 were unchanged, the plugin will send the checksum of the file, if the checksum exist in Artifactory, it will not deploy it again but will only create a "pointer" in the database to point to that location. If a file checksum doesn't exist in Artifactory it will then deploy it to Artifactory.

I'm guessing here that this request is to save network traffic and build time, if I'm wrong, could you please share the need behind the question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this applicable for multiple builds? I require it for version control and source code management. My server would already have those 10 files.. I do no need to deploy the same files again except the new version of the files.

Comment: It is for all of the files deployed to Artifactory. If you already have the file deployed and you are trying to deploy to a different location in Artifactory, only a pointer will be created and not the actual binary.